# Delayed Android Lock

Tags: android

If i press the Power button on a *Galaxy Nexus* device while running my native application there seems to be a ~5 second delay before my *Activity* gets the *onPause* notification. LogCat output:

```
08-29 20:06:27.751: I/PowerManagerService(391): Going to sleep by user request...
08-29 20:06:32.767: I/BlitzTech(22784): NotifyAndroidOnPause: notifyPauseRefCount: 1
```

Note the Power button is acknowledged at :27s but the *Activity* doesn't get notification until ~5 seconds later? (My *NotifyAndroidOnPause* function is simply called from *onPause*).

Has anyone come across this behaviour before?
I'm not calling any [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) methods at all.

(Android version: 4.2.2)

Many thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Firstm profile your app. Then see if you by any chance not doing any busy loops alike things in your code. Because if that problem occurs only when your app is in foreground, then apparently it's related to how you "behave" and in most cases extensive load is the culprit in such situations

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I'm actually in the process of trying to work out if i've got a stall somewhere. :)

EDIT: Though its bizarre it only seems to occur on my Galaxy Nexus. The lock is instant on my HTC One S.